# Spring application failed to load in Java 1.7

Tags: java, spring

We had recently migrated our web sphere from 8.5 to 8.5.5.14 and java from 1.6 to 1.7. My spring application works with java 1.6. When i tried to deploy in Java 1.7 it throws below exception on server startup. Not sure whats wrong with it. Can anyone please help. I am just posting the error details from the log...

```
>     [2/16/19 12:24:30:148 EST] 00000065 WASSessionCor I SessionContextRegistry getSessionContext SESN0176I: Will create a new
> session context for application key default_hostapps/TMS
>     [2/16/19 12:24:34:707 EST] 00000065 webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log SRVE0292I: Servlet Message -
> [TMSEAR#TMS.war]:.No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected
> on classpath
>     [2/16/19 12:24:34:908 EST] 00000065 webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log SRVE0292I: Servlet Message -
> [TMSEAR#TMS.war]:.Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'mydispatcher'
>     [2/16/19 12:24:34:909 EST] 00000065 DispatcherSer I org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
> FrameworkServlet 'mydispatcher': initialization started
>     [2/16/19 12:24:34:930 EST] 00000065 XmlWebApplica I org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext
> prepareRefresh Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace
> 'mydispatcher-servlet': startup date [Sat Feb 16 12:24:34 EST 2019];
> root of context hierarchy
>     [2/16/19 12:24:34:975 EST] 00000065 XmlBeanDefini I org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader
> loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext
> resource [/WEB-INF/config/dispatcher-servlet.xml]
>     [2/16/19 12:24:35:220 EST] 00000065 DefaultListab I org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory
> registerBeanDefinition Overriding bean definition for bean
> 'timesheetSubmitRemainderTask': replacing [Generic bean: class
> [com.tms.scheduleTasks.TimesheetSubmitRemainderTask]; scope=singleton;
> abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0;
> autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null;
> factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null;
> defined in file
> [C:\ICESAPPs\Projects\TMS\WebContent\WEB-INF\classes\com\tms\scheduleTasks\TimesheetSubmitRemainderTask.class]]
> with [Generic bean: class
> [com.tms.scheduleTasks.TimesheetSubmitRemainderTask]; scope=;
> abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0;
> autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null;
> factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null;
> defined in ServletContext resource
> [/WEB-INF/config/dispatcher-servlet.xml]]
>     [2/16/19 12:24:35:562 EST] 00000065 AutowiredAnno I org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
> <init> JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported
> for autowiring
>     [2/16/19 12:24:35:600 EST] 00000065 PostProcessor I org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker
> postProcessAfterInitialization Bean
> 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfiguration' of
> type [class
> org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1143cbab]
> is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for
> example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
>     [2/16/19 12:24:36:347 EST] 00000065 XmlWebApplica W org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext refresh
> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
> refresh attempt
>                                      org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'adminController': Injection of autowired
> dependencies failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
> autowire field: private com.tms.dao.MenuAccessDAO
> com.tms.controller.ServiceController.menuAccessDAO; nested exception
> is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'menuAccessDAO': Injection of autowired
> dependencies failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
> autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory
> com.tms.dao.MenuAccessDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext
> resource [/WEB-INF/config/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init
> method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.JoranException
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:664)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:630)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:678)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:490)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
>       at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:161)
```

Comment: What Spring version are you using?

Comment: Its spring 4.1   Java 1.7

Comment: slf4j says: "f you observe this problem, then it is **highly probable** that you have a **copy of commons-logging.jar** in your class path" ...

Comment: ..["websphere slf4j"](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21995397)

Comment: Thanks all for your help. I had added jar's which @Atul mentioned. I had a duplicate copy of Slf4.jar in my server lib folder. I had removed it and all the error are out and i can load application successfully. Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure at least one of below dependencies is present in your class path:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
     <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
     <version>1.2.3</version> 
 </dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

> Version you can choose which is compatible with other dependencies.

Comment: Now i see this error - Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory could not be successfully initialized. See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#unsuccessfulInit ....... How ever i had slf4j-log4j12.jar in my lib folder

Comment: I just figured it out, i had slf4j jar in the server lib folder as well. I had removed the jar from the server and it worked. Thanks @Atul.

Comment: @Atul...How are the jar's you said related to the error? Can you please elaborate. Thanks.

Comment: The exception you mentioned gave me the clue about the JARs. If your problem is solved then you can accept my answer as solution so that it can help others too.